# Как научить Sublime Text консольному вводу?

Tags: c++, gcc, sublime-text

В SublimeText 2.0.1 выбрал "Tools -> Build System -> C++", создал проект, добавил следующий файл:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "Enter two values: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    c = a + b;
    std::cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << c << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Build завершается удачно, но когда запускаю Run, строка std::cin >> a >> b; пропускается.

Comment: А вы уверены что в сублиме есть эмулятор терминала?

Comment: Как минимум там есть место для вывода, и вывод работает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Не умеет.

Слегка можно решить через SublimeREPL, запустив в нем шелл, но это не особо универсальное решение.